# G to H is a homomorphism, o(h) = 100, what are the values of o(g)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Question:
Let $\phi:G \rightarrow H$ be a homomorphism and let $g\in G$
and set $h=\phi(g)$.  Suppose $o(h)=100$.  Assume $g$ has
finite order.  What are the 
possible values of $o(g)$?

Attempt:
Because we know that $\phi(g)=h$ I took the 100th power of both sides and now hav $\phi(g)^{100}=h^{100} = e$ because the $o(h)=100$ implies $h^{100}=e$.

I'm not sure if this next step is true or the right approach but from this can I say that $\phi(g^{100})=e$?

Comment: That is correct but you only can draw the conclusion that $g^{100} \in ker(\phi)$. If $\phi$ is injective then $g^{100}=e$ and hence $o(g)$ must divide 100.

Comment: Yes, you can say that. When you're working by yourself, one technique to use when you come to something you have trouble proving is to see whether it is even useful by *blackboxing* (assuming) it and seeing if you can get a desirable result. In the circumstance it does yield something good, you will be motivated even more to validate that step.

Comment: I don't know if I can make that jump that $\phi$ is injective because the problem only states that it is a homomorphism and nothing else about it. If that was the case that would be nice but I'm not sure that I can do that.

Comment: If $m=o(g)$ then $e=\phi(e)=\phi(g^m)=\phi(g)^m=h^m$ and so $100$ divides $m$.

Comment: The key observation here isn't that $h^{100} = e$, it's that $h$ to any smaller power does *not* equal $e$...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that step is valid: Since $\phi$ is a homomorphism, $\phi(g^k) = \phi(g)^k$ for any $k$; this can be easily shown by induction on $k$, since

$$\phi(g^k) = \phi(g g^{k - 1}) = \phi(g) \phi(g^{k - 1}) = \phi(g) \phi(g)^{k - 1} = \phi(g)^k$$